# Для чего нужен метод RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions?

Tags: c#, .net

Для чего нужен и в каких случаях применяется на практике метод [RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.prepareconstrainedregions(v=vs.90).aspx)?

---

**Update:**

Пример кода, который не понял и в котором увидел этот метод:

```
var oldMode = GCSettings.LatencyMode;
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();

try
{
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.Batch;
}
finally
{
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = oldMode;
}
```

Comment: На практике он применяться не должен, вы просто не должны допускать в вашем приложении Thread.Abort. RuntimeHelpers — это функциональность для рантайм-библиотеки. Если она используется в коде, что-то не так с дизайном программы.

Comment: @VladD, добавил пример кода, в котором вообще его увидел. Но не понимаю что он делает в данном случае и зачем вообще его применили.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

CER — это сокращение для «constrained execution region», регион ограниченного выполнения. В нём запрещён выброс *внешних* для кода исключений, не спровоцированных на языковом уровне — например, `ThreadAbortException`, `OutOfMemoryException`, `StackOverflowException`*.

Непосредственно за объявлением `RuntimeServices.PrepareConstrainedRegions();` должен следовать блок `try`[/`catch`][/`finally`], в котором `catch`-часть, а также `finally`-часть превращается в регион ограниченного выполнения.

Для вашего кода это значит, что код `GCSettings.LatencyMode = oldMode;` не будет прерван внешними условиями. Это может быть важно, так как он меняет состояние *всей* программы.

CER не нужно в нормальном коде. Ваше приложение никогда не должно вызывать `Thread.Abort`, а переполнения стека просто не должно допускать. Поэтому писать код, «предохранящий» от этого, просто не нужно.

Дополнительное скучное чтение по теме:

- [Constrained Execution Regions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions)
- [Code demonstrating the importance of a Constrained Execution Region](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101147/276994)
- [Keep Your Code Running with the Reliability Features of the .NET Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423173148/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx)

---

*Для того, чтобы это работало, ваш код внутри региона *обязан* вызывать только код с `ReliabilityContract`'ом, не проводить аллокаций памяти, не делать виртуальных вызовов прямо или косвенно, вызовов через рефлексию, `lock`, сериализации, работы с многомерными массивами (!) и т. п. Ответственность за это лежит на программисте, поэтому если CER «не работает», виноват скорее всего программист.

Comment: А что не так с `is`/`as`?

Comment: Кстати, ASP.NET часто "развлекается" с Thread.Abort (там это стандартный механизм завершения запроса) - так что я бы не сказал что CER не нужно в нормальном коде. Если, конечно, не считать любой код на ASP.NET за ненормальный :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Моя ошибка, по третьей ссылке там «isinst and castclass instructions **on COM objects**». Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ыыыыы! Но Thread.Abort — это же зло? Тогда и не знаю, что сказать. Что, если код в этот момент редактировал глобальную структуру данных?

Comment: А вы знаете какой-то другой адекватный вариант обработки ситуации "пользователь ушел со страницы пока она загружалась"?

Comment: Ну, кроме кооперативной отмены через CancellationToken, которая моложе чем ASP.NET

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кооперативная отмена — вроде бы единственный метод, рекомендованный Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Assembly: CLSCompliant(False)>
<Security.SecurityCritical()>
Dim v = Sub(z)
                    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions()
                    Dim a = Sub(x)
                                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions()
                                Try
                                Finally
                                    '"Непрерываемый" код
                                End Try
                            End Sub
                    Dim c = Sub()
                                '"Непрерываемый" код
                            End Sub
                    Call Sub() RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(a, c, nothing)
                End Sub     
Call Function() v.DynamicInvoke({})
```

А что если так? :) Например для обработки SecureString

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]